# Equivalent of rowsum function for Matrix-class (dgCMatrix)

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, rowsum

For the base R matrix class we have the `rowsum` function, which is very fast for computing column sums across groups of rows.

Is there an equivalent function or approach implemented in the Matrix-package?

I'm particularly interested in a fast alternative to `rowsum` for large dgCMatrix-objects (i.e. millions of rows, but roughly 95% sparse).

Comment: check `slam` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slam/slam.pdf

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but `Matrix::rowSums` might be the function you are looking for.

Comment: `Matrix::rowSums()` is a replacement for `base::rowSums()` (which computes the sum of every row, returning a vector), not `base::rowsum()` (which combines rows in specified groups, returning a matrix with a smaller number of rows)

Answer (score 1):

The [DelayedArray](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DelayedArray.html) BioConductor package now has a rowsum function that accepts sparse matrices that has been very fast when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using matrix multiplication, based on an example in https://slowkow.com/notes/sparse-matrix/. First, let's create a sparse matrix to play with,

```
library(magrittr)
library(forcats)
library(stringr)
library(Matrix)

set.seed(42)
m <- sparseMatrix(
  i = sample(x = 1e4, size = 1e4),
  j = sample(x = 1e4, size = 1e4),
  x = rnorm(n = 1e4)
)
colnames(m) <- str_c("col", seq(ncol(m)))
rownames(m) <- str_c("row", seq(nrow(m)))
```

and a grouping vector defining which rows to sum,

```
group <- sample(1:10, nrow(m), replace = TRUE) %>%
  paste0("new_row", .) %>%
  fct_inorder
```

Whether `group` is a factor and its level order will affect the final row order in the merged matrix. I made `group` a factor with levels ordered by first appearance in `group` to make the row order resemble that from the `rowsum()` operation with `reorder = FALSE`.

Next, we create a (sparse) matrix that we can left-multiply by `m` to get a version of `m` whose rows have been summed based on `group`,

```
group_mat <- sparse.model.matrix(~ 0 + group) %>% t
# Adjust row names to get the correct final row names
rownames(group_mat) <- rownames(group_mat) %>% str_extract("(?<=^group).+")

msum <- group_mat %*% m
```

The result matches `base::rowsum()` on the dense version of the matrix,

```
d <- as.matrix(m)
dsum <- rowsum(d, group, reorder = FALSE)
all.equal(as.matrix(msum), dsum)
#> [1] TRUE
```

but the sparse-matrix multiplication method is much faster,

```
bench::mark( msum <- group_mat %*% m )$median
#> [1] 344µs
bench::mark( dsum <- rowsum(d, group) )$median
#> [1] 146ms
```